# Use libfreenects waitForNewFrame with timeout on Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, c++11, openkinect

I have a Qt application which controls 2 Kinects via libfreenect. To access the Kinects, I use one Qt-thread. All works perfectly so far. But I need the program to continue working when one Kinect is disconnected. But if so, the program get stuck in the `waitForNewFrame` call, even when I specify a timeout parameter. The documentation says, that '*this parameter is ignored if not built with C++11 threading support*'.

What must be built with C++11 threading support? Libfreenect or my Qt App?

And how do I build with C++11 threading support?

The Qt App is built with qmake. I have a Global.pri where I can define compiler switches. Compiler is clang but gcc should work too.

Libfreenect is built in an automated build script. It git-clones a fork of  libfreenect and executes:

```
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem.

C++11 needs to be enabled during compilation by adding the `-DENABLE_CXX11=ON` argument to the `cmake` command.